# Chain Rule Puzzle

Tags: calculus, derivatives, chain-rule

Here is an old question:
If $\boldsymbol{s_r}$
denote the sum of the $\boldsymbol{r}$ th powers of the roots of the
equation

$$\boldsymbol{x^n+p_1x^{n-1}+\cdots +p_n=0}$$
prove that if the coefficients be expressed in terms of
$\boldsymbol{s_r}$
then will
$$\boldsymbol{\frac{dp_{r+k}}{ds_r}=-\frac{p_k}{r}}$$
[Brioschi.]

If we just consider the case $n=3$ and attempt to verify it for $\frac{dp_3}{ds_2}$ then we have Newton's identities,

$$-3p_3=s_1p_2+s_2p_1+s_3$$
$$-2p_2=p_1s_1+s_2$$
$$-p_1=s_1$$

Which give

$$\frac{dp_2}{ds_2}=-\frac{1}{2}$$
$$\frac{dp_3}{ds_2}=-\frac{p_1}{2}$$
So this seems to verify the question.

However a different solution is possible, using the chain rule and this does not seem to work,

$$\frac{dp_3}{ds_2}=\frac{dp_3}{dx_1}\frac{dx_1}{ds_2}+\frac{dp_3}{dx_2}\frac{dx_2}{ds_2}+\frac{dp_3}{dx_2}\frac{dx_3}{ds_2}$$
And taking

$$\frac{dx_i}{ds_2}=1/\frac{ds_2}{dx_i}=\frac{1}{2x_i}$$
(this is legitimate right ?)
I have the sum

$$\frac{dp_3}{ds_2}=\frac{x_2x_3}{2x_1}+\frac{x_1x_3}{2x_2}+\frac{x_2x_2}{2x_3}$$

and this is not equal to the previous answer.

What is the error in this second method ?

Comment: I think you are dealing with partial derivatives, so the last but one equality is incorrect. You need to invert the matrix of partial derivative and look at the corresponding entry.  The result is nevertheless very beautiful.   Are you interested in a solution or only where the mistake is?

Answer (score 3):

Just because the result is so nice, let's try to prove it.

We have the identity
$$(x-x_1)\cdots(x-x_n) = x^n + p_1 x^{n-1} + \cdots + p_n$$
so we can also write
$$(1- x_1 x)\cdots (1- x_n x) = 1 + p_1 x + p_2 x^2 + \cdots + p_n x^n$$

Consider the above as (formal) series in $x$ and take the $\log$. We get
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \log (1 - x_i x) = \log (1 + p_1 x + \cdots + p_n x^n)$$.

Now recall that $\log (1-u) = -(u + \frac{u^2}{2} + \frac{u^3}{3} +\cdots)$, so we get
$$ -(s_1 x + \frac{s_2}{2} x^2 + \frac{s_3}{3} x^3 + \cdots ) = \log ( 1 + p_1 x + \cdots + p_n x^n)$$

Now, let $D$ be any derivation. From the above we
$$-\sum_{k\ge 1} \frac{D(s_k) x^k}{k} \cdot  \sum_{i=0}^n p_i x^i = \sum_{i=1}^n D(p_i) x^i$$

Now consider $D = \frac{\partial}{\partial s_r}$ for $1\le r \le n$ and identify the coefficients of $x$.  We get the required equalities ( and some more).

Comment: Nice method. I was more interested in the chain rule failure, but dont delete your answer. I realize now that the matrix must be inverted. A different and conceptually easier proof can be given by differentiating Newton's identity, $-(r+k)p_{r+k}=p_{r+k-1}s_1+\cdots +s_{r+k}$.

Comment: Thank you!  Would you perhaps post your solution too?  I wonder if you can  in fact find the inverse of the matrix too.  Interesting question.